# Drag and drop a shap to another pane in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, shapes, class-diagram

Hey guys im new here and searched through all questions I could find but didn't find an answer that could solve my problem.
So I am trying to create a "Use case Diagram Creator" within JavaFx but I can't get the Drag and Drop Method done. Like the title says I created Shapes in the Scene Builder and putted them on the left site of a Splitpane. On the right side I placed a new Simple Pane which is the area the Shapes should be dropped in.

That is my fxml file:

```
<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.UseCaseController">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <SplitPane fx:id="splitPanelo" dividerPositions="0.2591397849462366" prefHeight="961.0" prefWidth="1437.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="rotate" layoutX="256.0" layoutY="872.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Rotate" />
                  <Ellipse fill="#0d5a505e" layoutX="183.0" layoutY="191.0" radiusX="104.0" radiusY="50.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                  <Rectangle fx:id="rect" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#0d594f5c" height="100.0" layoutX="83.0" layoutY="282.0" onDragDetected="#smthDetected" onDragDropped="#smthDropped" onDragOver="#smthOver" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
                  <Line endX="100.0" layoutX="183.0" layoutY="471.0" startX="-100.0" />
                  <MenuBar prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="1437.0">
                    <menus>
                      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                        <items>
                          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="New" />
                            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
                        </items>
                      </Menu>
                      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                        <items>
                          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                        </items>
                      </Menu>
                      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                        <items>
                          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                        </items>
                      </Menu>
                    </menus>
                  </MenuBar>
                  <Button fx:id="createTf" layoutX="49.0" layoutY="872.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Create Textfield" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="724.0" prefWidth="732.0">
               <children>
                  <Pane fx:id="dropZone" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="58.0" prefHeight="797.0" prefWidth="1025.0" />
                  <ScrollBar layoutX="1011.0" layoutY="-254.0" orientation="VERTICAL" />
                  <Button fx:id="back" layoutX="964.0" layoutY="893.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#backpressed" text="←" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@UseCaseWindow.css" />
    </stylesheets>
</GridPane>
```

This is my controller:

```
public class UseCaseController {

    double oldX;
    double oldY;
    Rectangle draggingrect;

    @FXML
    Pane dropZone;

    @FXML
    Button back;

    @FXML
    Shape rect;

    public void smthOver(DragEvent de) {
        Dragboard db = de.getDragboard();
        de.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
        System.out.println("Dragging over");
        de.consume();

    }

    public void smthDropped(DragEvent de) {
        Dragboard board = de.getDragboard();
        de.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);


        double dragX = de.getSceneX();
        double dragY = de.getSceneY();

        double newPosX = dragX + oldX;
        double newPosY = dragY + oldY;

        rect.setLayoutX(newPosX);
        rect.setLayoutY(newPosY);

        de.setDropCompleted(true);
        System.out.println("Drag Dropped");
        de.consume();

    }

    public void smthDetected(MouseEvent de){
        Dragboard db = rect.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString(rect.getId());
        db.setContent(content);
        oldX = rect.getTranslateX();
        oldY = rect.getTranslateY();
        System.out.println("Drag detected");
        de.consume();
    }
```

Sorry if it looks a bit messy I tried different ways I found here but I won't find a method that would let me add the new dragged Rectangle to the new Pane. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See D&D [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44878414/3992939).For more specific help please post [mcve]

Comment: Sorry for the long response time I got problems with my internet. Thank you for the example first it helped me pretty well and I tried to use it for my problem. In general it works but when the shape is dragged in the new Pane I can only move it like 3 mm at a time then there is a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException and i have to drag it again. Thanks in advance if the new Code is needed i can post it

Comment: Please post a new question with [mcve].  Send me a message here so I know about it.

Comment: @c0der made the new post. thanks